# Parsing JSON objects in an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to print out the value of "title" for each object, with a delay before the next title replaces the current one. My JSON:

```
{"articles":[  
     "author":"author1",
     "title":"title1",
     "description":"description1"
  },
  {  
     "author":"author2",
     "title":"title2",
     "description":"description2"
    }
  ]
  }
```

and my code

```
$(function getNews(){
 $.getJSON(
"https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=",function out(json){
  showNews(json)
});
function showNews(json){
  arr =[];
$.each(json.articles, function(index, value) {
    arr.push(value.title);
});
  for(k =0; k< arr.length; k++){
    console.log(arr[k]);
  }
  setTimeout(function(){getNews()},4000);}});
```

What I'm getting now is the for-loop running once, and printing all values of the array at the same time.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use setTimeout inside foreach

Comment: A call to setTimeout is async. The cursor will continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [
    {
        "author": "author1",
        "title": "title1",
        "description": "description1"
    },
    {
        "author": "author2",
        "title": "title2",
        "description": "description2"
    }
];

for (let index in array) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(array[index])
    }, 1000 * index)
}
```

This is an example of using timeout.

It will console out each item every second.

You can modify it as you want to do whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a closure around setTimeout using an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) like below:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(index); }, i * 1000);
    })(i);
}
```